# Excel data validation expanding incorrectly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure the correct way to word this.

I have an Excel sheet with an entire column of data validation.
The data validation expands, for example row 2's data validation is ='Lookup List 1'!A2#
Row 3's data validation is ='Lookup List 1'!A3#... etc

When I insert a row into the middle of my data, say at row 100, row 100 is fine but all the rows below it that got pushed down are now off by 1 (aka row 101 is referencing A100 instead of A101)

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.
Apparently making the cells absolute references does not help when new rows are added.
So, I used an INDIRECT formula to always tell it to reference the row number of the current row

```
=INDIRECT("'Lookup List 1'!A"&ROW(F2))#
```

Answer (score 1):

Lock the cell reference on your data validation reference. Alternatively, you can name the range and reference the range in data validation.